# Velocity induced by a straight vortex filament

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-dynamics, vortex

Consider a straight vortex filament as shown below. At each point, there's a point vortex of strength $\it T$. Consider that a point $P$ is there on the outermost circle of flow induced by the vortex about the origin $O$. That is the point $P$ lies in the plane containing the flow induced by the vortex at $O$. So, the only point on the vortex filament that will induce a flow at point $P$ is $O$.

Therefore, the vortex at point $O^{'}$ will not induce any flow at point $P$. Vortex at point $O^{'}$ can only induce flow at those points that are in the plane containing the flow induced by the vortex at $O^{'}$.

[image: Vortex Filament]

So, my question is how Biot-Savart Law is applied for a straight filament vortex? How can the segment $dl$ induce a flow at a point $P$ that is not in the plane? Only the vortex centered at the point of intersection of line and perpendicular from point $P$ to the line can induce the flow at $P$. Please clear my query.

[image: Biot-Savart Law]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think in 3D. A vortex will induce a flow speed everywhere.

> That is the point  lies in the plane containing the flow induced by the vortex at

Why would you think that vorticity induces a speed only in one plane? You start from the wrong presupposition.

Now consider the rings around the vortex filament in your first drawing. All around those rings a flow speed is induced. Its magnitude drops with the inverse of the radius of one particular ring but is constant along the circumference of that ring. Actually, that ring is only a section through an infinitesimal tube, just as infinitesimal as that vortex filament.

[image: Induced speed of a vortex]

Irrotational vortex. © Silver Spoon, picture [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Irrotational_vortex.gif).

Also, the symbol for vortex strength is a capital Greek letter Gamma ($\Gamma$), not $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Now, I understood that I had a wrong idea about the 3D vortex filament.

Comment: @Peter vortex induce velocity because of viscosity? if you start rotate spoon in the middle of bucket of water, after some time all the water will spinning in that direction..so at zero viscosity induction is zero? Is this theory talk about that?

Comment: @user628075 vorticity ≠ viscosity!

Comment: @PeterKämpf So what is mechanism how vorticity induced velocity?

Comment: @user628075 That is the part which makes potential flow theory so unintuitive. The idea is that it works like electromagnetic induction, following the same laws. Of course, in reality viscosity is needed, but potential flow theory assumes inviscid flow. I only wanted to point out the mistake in your comment. The answer nowhere refers to viscosity.

Comment: @PeterKämpf How this theory works if that is not what is happening in real fluid? This is unbelievable

Comment: @user628075 Please leave questions of belief to your religious authority. Here we deal with a theory which helped to explain and predict flow effects with little computational effort. It did its job when nothing else did. And still does today.

Comment: @PeterKämpf yes it  deliver results with maybe 60% accuracy